# Is there anyway of forcing a javascript GET request before rendering html with Splash?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm getting stucked loading a dynamic content from this website with Splash:

https://www.fravega.com/l/tv-y-video/tv/?categorias=tv-y-video%2Ftv&page=1

I'm trying to get the href attribute from this [element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgKSF.png):
`<a data-type="next" data-active="false" data-test-id="pagination-next-button" href="/l/tv-y-video/tv/?categorias=tv-y-video%2Ftv&amp;page=2" class="sc-efd39989-3 eHIrnc" style="pointer-events: unset;"><span>Siguiente &gt;</span></a>` into render.html, but since it's generated by javascript I can't find a way to tell Splash to run it in its [scripts panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUYEY.png)

```
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(0.5))
    return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
        har = splash:har(),
    }
end
```

I've tried every solution that [Splash FAQs](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly) suggests, but it didn't render it yet

Here is my environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Docker image: scrapinghub/splash::latest

If anyone could help me, I'd be really thankful

**PD: The solution should be Python/Scrapy friendly because this response should be generated from a scrapy spider!** But allow me to do that work

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in your question, not an image.